# Android :Programmatically go back FragmentActivity from fragment

Tags: android, android-studio

Iam new to android .I need to go back to the FragmentActivity from fragment page.

My work flow is:

MainActivity->ProfileActivity->ProfilePhotoEditFragment

I need to go back to

ProfilePhotoEditFragment -> ProfileActivity

manifest

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="16" />
```

ProfilePhotoEditFragment.java

```
public class ProfilePhotoEditFragment extends Fragment implements OnClickListener {

ViewUtils mViewUtils;
Bundle mSavedInstanceState;

private OnNavigateProfileListener mOnNavigateProfileListener;
private Button mCancelButton;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Context mContext = getActivity().getApplicationContext();
    mViewUtils = new ViewUtils(mContext);

}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    mSavedInstanceState = savedInstanceState;

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_edit_profile_pic, container, false);
    mCancelButton = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.cancel);
    mCancelButton.setOnClickListener(this);

    return view;
}

@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();

}

@Override
public void onClick(View view) {

   if (view.getId() == mCancelButton.getId()){
        onBackPressed();

    }

}

public void onBackPressed() {
    // do something on back.
    return;
}
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

remove current fragment ProfilePhotoEditFragment in onBackPressed()

```
if (getSupportFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount() == 0) {

        //( "stackzeo");
    } else {
        getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStack();
        removeCurrentFragment();
        //("stacknotzeo");
    }
```

..

```
public void removeCurrentFragment() {

    Fragment currentFrag = (Fragment) getFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.content_frame);

    if (currentFrag != null)
        getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().remove(currentFrag);

    getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().commit();

}
```

Call findFragmentById() on FragmentManager and determine which fragment is in your R.id.content_frame container.

Comment: getSupportFragmentManager(), which is only available in FragmentActivity.

Comment: use getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager()

Answer (score 0):

just write down

```
 public void onBackPressed(){

    super.onBackPressed(); 

 }
```

Comment: While adding following code  it showing "Cannot resolve method 'onBackPressed()'"

Comment: why this will not work. The problem is that onBackPressed() was not working.

Comment: Because this" super.onBackPressed();" is applicable in FragmentActivity .

Answer (score 0):

Thank you All. this my working code

```
....

@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
   if (view.getId() == mCancelButton.getId()){
        getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStack();
        removeCurrentFragment();
    }

}


public void removeCurrentFragment()
{
    FragmentTransaction transaction = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    Fragment currentFrag =  getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_common_profile_layout);

    String fragName = "NONE";
    if (currentFrag!=null)
        fragName = currentFrag.getClass().getSimpleName();

    if (currentFrag != null)
        transaction.remove(currentFrag);
    transaction.commit();

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
getActivity().onBackPressed();
```

You should be able to call this code from every fragment.

Please check, if getActivity() returns null.

Hope this helps.